# How to connect to an external API using JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

It has been a while since I've written PHP and AJAX. So please bear with me.

I am trying to use AltosResearch's API for Home Listing History Charts/Comps. API doc at: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1hHPmUEuV5ekqXTLN8RcEOyzhiBLZSz2eFUuV1_Mu7fg#h.fc47gnpln3dt

User will enter home address in provided form. An ajax request will get JSON info from AltosResearch.
Historical Information and Home Comparables will then be provided. However I am not getting any info back from Altos. I know I can't use JSONP since I am connecting to an external host. So I used curl to retrieve info. What am I doing wrong here?

Please help. Thank you.

The JSON response from Altos has the following format:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "unit_number": "",
            "property_id": "a08373408624b1570ff6aafb77498308",
            "baths": "1.00",
            "zip": "94086",
            "geocode_accuracy": "",
            "residence_sqft": "765",
            "year_built": "1942",
            "street_name": "CALIFORNIA",
            "state": "CA",
            "lot_sqft": "4900",
            "data_capture_date": "2011-08-26",
            "city": "SUNNYVALE",
            "days_on_market": "",
            "price": "388000",
            "beds": "2.00",
            "street_address_raw": "800 E CALIFORNIA AV",
            "street_direction": "EAST",
            "longitude": "",
            "street_number": "800",
            "latitude": "",
            "listing_entry_id": "caf478d031f90abd0131fe7caff77ea7",
            "residence_type": "single_family",
            "street_type": "AVENUE"
        }
    ],
    "responseCode": 200,
    "apiVersion": 1
}
```

Here is my JS file:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#altos").on('submit', function(event) {

        function errorFunction() {
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "There was an error with JSON's callback function!";
        }

        // Request the JSON and process it
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          async: true,
          url: 'http://data.altosresearch.com/altos/app',
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= "Property IDs: " + data.list[0].property_id + data.list[0].listing_entry_id;
          },
          error: function() {
            errorFunction();
          }
        });

        return false;
        event.preventDefault();

      });

    });
  </script>
```

Here's my PHP file:

```
  // Using GET
  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://data.altosresearch.com/altos/app");
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $page_data = curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);

  // Access data with GET or POST via retrieve_page fun
  function retrieve_page($url, $post_parameters = null) {
    // Connect and fetches data
    $query_string = null;
    if(!is_null($post_parameters)) {
      if(!is_array($post_parameters)) {
        die("Form parameters need to be in an array format");
      }
    }
    // Build query string
    $query_string = http_build_query($post_parameters);
  }


  // Configure connection to use query string as POST data
  $ch = curl_init();

  if ($query_string) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $return_data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return_data;
  }

  // Extract params from the form
  $qs = http_build_query(array(
    "pai"       =>  "755110180",
    "apiv"      =>  "1",
    "service"   =>   "listinghistory",
    "st"        =>  $_REQUEST["st"],
    "c"         =>  $_REQUEST["c"],
    "z"         =>  $_REQUEST["z"],
    "addr"      =>  $_REQUEST["addr"]
  ));

  if(isset($_GET['st'], $_GET['c'], $_GET['z'], $_GET['addr'])) { 

    $pai = $_GET['pai'];
    $apiv = $_GET['apiv'];
    $service = $_GET['service'];
    $st = $_GET['st'];
    $c = $_GET['c'];
    $z = $_GET['z'];
    $addr = $_GET['addr'];

    $qs['pai'] = $pai;
    $qs['apiv'] = $apiv;
    $qs['service'] = $service;
    $qs['st'] = $st;
    $qs['c'] = $c;
    $qs['z'] = $z;
    $qs['addr'] = $addr;
  }

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($qs);

  $page = retrieve_page("http://data.altosresearch.com/altos/app?$qs");
  echo ("<hr>page info: " . $page . ".<hr>");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> url: 'http://data.altosresearch.com/altos/app',
> ```

You are trying to request the data directly from altosresearch instead of from your PHP program, so you are still subject to the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: So how do I get around that? Is curl the best way for getting json objects from an external API through PHP or is there any other options? Thanks.